# Using Text causes an error even though the compiler suggests it

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am probably misreading the suggestion of the compiler, but when I try to pass it a `Text` value, it complains.

Adapting the websocket [example](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/e2e546df4d062e182da79a20115d1334055ee1a9/yesod-websockets/chat.hs#L31-L34) I try to pass an encoded object. I've simplified my example to the following, where I try to just pass `"someText" :: Text`:

```
race_
    (forever $ atomically (readTChan readChan) >>= sendTextData)
    (sourceWS $$ mapM_C (\msg -> atomically $ writeTChan writeChan ("someText" :: Text)))
```

However, I get this error message:

```
No instance for (websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types.WebSocketsData
                   a0)
  arising from a use of ‘sourceWS’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types.WebSocketsData
             Text
    -- Defined in ‘websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types’
  instance websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types.WebSocketsData
             Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text
    -- Defined in ‘websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types’
  instance websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types.WebSocketsData
             ByteString
    -- Defined in ‘websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types’
  ...plus one other
In the first argument of ‘($$)’, namely ‘sourceWS’
In the second argument of ‘race_’, namely
  ‘(sourceWS
    $$
      mapM_C
        (\ msg -> atomically $ writeTChan writeChan ("someText" :: Text)))’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  race_
    (forever $ atomically (readTChan readChan) >>= sendTextData)
    (sourceWS
     $$
       mapM_C
         (\ msg -> atomically $ writeTChan writeChan ("someText" :: Text)))
```

Comment: There are several problems with the source you are providing, which should include imports. The problem will quickly be resolved if you specialise `sourceWS` to `sourceWSText :: MonadIO m => ConduitM i Text (WebSocketsT m) (); sourceWSText = sourceWS`

Answer (score 2):

```
sourceWS :: (MonadIO m, WebSocketsData a) => Producer (WebSocketsT m) a
```

I presume that `$$` and `mapM_C` somehow attach the output `a` to the argument `msg` of the lambda `\msg -> ...`. But, you never use `msg`, so there is no way for the compiler to determine the type `a` it should choose for `sourceWS`, as it said:

> ```
> No instance for (websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Types.WebSocketsData
>                a0)
>   arising from a use of ‘sourceWS’
> The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
> ```

Comment: I see. Do you know how I could fix this, to allow passing the `Text`?

Comment: If you really intend to ignore `msg` you can force it to have a type with `\(msg :: Text) -> ...` using `ScopedTypeVariables`. Or you can put a specialized `sourceWSText :: MonadIO m => ConduitM i Text (WebSocketsT m) (); sourceWSText = sourceWS` somewhere in the file and use `sourceWSText` instead. The compiler doesn't know what sort of `WebSocketsData` `sourceWS` is producing. If you had used `msg`, e.g. appending it to "someText", the compiler would know what it was dealing with and could choose the right instance for `sourceWS`

Comment: You could also write, e.g. `(msg \`asTypeOf\` "someText" :: Text)`

Comment: Specializing the types is indeed working, thank you!